# Registering a COM object with only an IDL file

Tags: c++, com, registration, idl

I have a third-party [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29) file which, when compiled, generates a header and an _i.c file. All three of these files are part of a Visual Studio 2010 project. (So far the project is empty other than attempted COM initialization stuff.)

I can get the project to compile by calling

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
CoCreateInstance(stuff);
```

At runtime CoCreateInstance() returns a "Class not registered" error.

Everything I can find on the Internet says to register a COM object by running regsvr32 on the DLL file or EXE file. However I only have an IDL file. I tried registering the EXE file generated by the project, but I got an error saying the module was "loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found."

I'm honestly not sure what else to try.

Comment: Normally such an IDL is associated with a .dll that you install as a COM object with regsvr32.  Does the third party from whom you obtained the idl supply such a .dll or other software that you can install?

Comment: It would help if you told us a little about what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to call a COM object the third-party provides?  Implement a COM object the third-party expects you to provide?  something else?

Comment: Why did somebody give you this IDL file?  Was the message that came with it: "here, implement this"?  You are looking at a pretty steep learning curve if you do, consider giving it back.  Or learn ATL.  Or C#, it is definitely easier to get going in that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDL files define interfaces, not implementations. If literally all you have of this third-party component is an IDL file then you have nothing you could register.

It's possible that the IDL file describes interfaces you're to implement that third-party code calls into; in that case you wouldn't CoCreateInstance them, they might CoCreateInstance you. But given the amount of information, I'm leaning towards you're missing the actual third-party component or you're passing the wrong thing to CoCreateInstance.

Comment: You are correct. It turns out that I was missing the dll that implements the idl.

Answer (score 2):

An [IDL File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Interface Definition File) does not provide any implementation for the types declered on it; it only specifies how you  can communicate with classes coded in a DLL that **implements** the IDL file.

The IDL file is not enough, you will also need the DLL that implements it.